# OpenGL and Changing NSWindow size

Tags: macos, opengl, osx-lion

I'm modifying a Cocoa program that uses OpenGL (and I'm a raw beginner on OpenGL). I'm trying to allow it to go to Lion's fullscreen mode and scale the window from whatever size it currently has to be as big as possible in the current screen. When I go to fullscreen, the window is scaled up, but the program only uses the upper left corner, and the rest of the window is VRAM trash. I increase the size of the frame of the window and the content rect, and call glScalef (with the correct value) to ramp up the scale, but it never seems to change scale on the screen. It seems that I'm stuck with whatever width/height I initially pass to -NSWindow:initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:.  Any suggestions on where I need to look?

Comment: Sounds like you might be missing a call to `glViewport`, though without seeing code can't be sure. A screenshot of the issue may be helpful as well.